# Change subquery into windows functioning

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have a table I want to add a new column to create new feature I have my query I thought it will work but I am still struggling to get it solved some people suggested me to use windows functioning and get this done but I am totally confused how do I get it done.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    case WHEN lagged_bool = 'NULL' THEN
        (case WHEN qty < 5000 THEN
            'TRUE'
        ELSE 
            'FALSE' 
        END)
    ELSE 
        lagged_bool
    END AS predicting_bool
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,  
        CASE WHEN oute.predicted_bool = 'CONFUSED' THEN
            (
                SELECT 
                    first_value(inter.predicted_bool) over (partition by oute.id_partners, oute.id_accounts ORDER BY  inter.dt_metrics_us desc)
                FROM sandbox.dlpred_7_csv AS inter
                WHERE inter.predicted_bool IN ('TRUE','FALSE')
            )
        ELSE 
            'NULL'
        END AS lagged_venue
    FROM sandbox.dl_pred_7_csv AS oute
)
```

I want the above query to be transformed equivalent to windows functions or some different form but not in the sub query form.

Comment: could u please add sample data and your expected output in the question

Comment: Before we go down the windows function road can you confirm you are on mysql 8 or above or can migrate to 8 or above?

Comment: You have posted a question which doesn't state what you are trying to do and a query which doen't work (and is poorly formatted). It would help if you reviewed your question and provided sample data and expected output as text in the quetsion.

Comment: Surely will add detailed description along with the data sorry for inconvenience